# Using intent inside OncheckedChanged

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

May i know how should i call the intent to next activity in this line?(case 3)
It is inside OncheckedChanged of a switch.

I was getting the error

```
Home.this cannot be referenced from static context
```

My activity is as follow:

```
......
.....

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = new View(this.getActivity());
            ARG_NUMBER = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, 0);

            switch (ARG_NUMBER) {
                case 1:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stamp, container, false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
                    //to be optimize
                    Switch passcode_switch = (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                    passcode_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                            if(isChecked){
                                Log.d("Switch State=", "" + "Is checked");
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Generated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                final Intent setup_passcode = new Intent(Home.this, Passcode.class);
                                startActivity(setup_passcode);

                            }else{
                                Log.d("Switch State=", "" + "NOT checked");

                            }
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
            return rootView;
....
....
```

i cannot call intent for the line:

```
final Intent setup_passcode = new Intent(Home.this, Passcode.class);
                                startActivity(setup_passcode);
```

Comment: Hi can you show the whole class you implemented? :)

Comment: unrelated to the question: I suggest you use fragments.

Comment: `final Intent setup_passcode = new Intent(compoundButton.getContext(), Passcode.class);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
final Intent setup_passcode = new Intent(Home.this, Passcode.class);
```

to

```
final Intent setup_passcode = new Intent(getActivity(), Passcode.class);
```

get context by using `getActivity()` in `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have solved it by yourself as for displaying toast

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Generated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

you are using getActivity(), so same way for getting context to be used in intent you can use getActivity as

```
final Intent setup_passcode = new Intent(getActivity(), Passcode.class);
startActivity(setup_passcode);
```